# How to upload multiple files parallely to S3 bucket in react-native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3

I am using [react-native-s3-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-s3-upload) package in react-native to upload images to s3 bucket directly from react-native code but here I can upload only a single file at a time as shown below

```
const file = {                    //want to replace this with an array of files object

  uri: "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=655DBE66-8008-459C-9358-914E1FB532DD&ext=PNG",
  name: "image.png",
  type: "image/png"
}
 
const options = {
  keyPrefix: "uploads/",
  bucket: "your-bucket",
  region: "us-east-1",
  accessKey: "your-access-key",
  secretKey: "your-secret-key",
  successActionStatus: 201
}
 
RNS3.put(file, options).then(response => {
  if (response.status !== 201)
    throw new Error("Failed to upload image to S3");
  console.log(response.body);

});
```

Now to upload 10 files I have to run a for loop to upload all files to S3 one by one,

Is there any way to upload all the files at once, as commented above I want to replace file variable from object to an array of files object

Comment: For those who are looking for the answer since RNS3.put return a promise so if we have 10-20 files we can use Promise.all([array of RNS3.put promises]) to upload it almost parallely, instead if uploading 1 by1